# Как работает постинкремент оператор?

Tags: java

Есть код (**обновлен**):

```
int s = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    s = s + s++;
}
System.out.println(s);
```

Собственно вопрос, почему `s` после цикла будет равна `0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что присвоение s = срабатывает **после** того, как отработает увеличение s++.

По шагам:

1. сначала значение s увеличивается на 1, значение в памяти обновляется
2. потом s++ возвращает предыдущее значение, т.е. 0
3. выполняется операция присвоения и перезатирает значение s в памяти обратно на 0

Если бы вы использовали ++s, то всё было бы иначе. На шаге 2 ++s вернуло бы 1, как и ожидалос. Правда при этом конструкция "s = ++s" ничем бы не отличалась от "++s" или "s++", кроме лишней операции записи в память.

**UPD** c учётом изменения в листинге, как и говорил yozh, объяснение остаётся в силе

есть выражение s = s + s++

1. берётся левая часть выражения, до "+", слева стоит s.. там всё ещё 0.
2. берётся правая часть выражения, после "+".. там s++.. выполняется инкремент и записывается в s = 1, но возвращается 0
3. Выполняется сложение 0 + 0
4. Выполняется запись в переменную s = 0, так что результат инкремента перезатирается и теряется.

Comment: cy6erGn0m, немного не так написал листинг
s = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
    s = s + s++;
}
System.out.println(s); //тут s = 0; (уже после отработки цикла)

на сколько я понимаю логику:

1. s = 0;
2. заходим в цикл. на первой итерации:
 s = s + s++;
фактически получаем:
s = 0 + 0;
3. s инкрементится
4. проверка условия и переход на след итерацию.
Но видимо что-то не так работает(

Comment: @corri лучше исправляйте код в вопросе

Comment: Объяснение @cy6erGn0m все так же валидно для нового случая. Главная фишка в том, что `s++` *возвращает* старое значение. Но *присваивание* нового значения переменной `s` происходит во время самого инкремента.

Answer (score 1):

Переменная s увеличится на единицу только после выполнения ВСЕГО блока, если надо, чтобы она увеличила значение ДО выполнения блока, надо написать `++s`.

---

Немного переработал ваш код, я сам только начинаю работать с java, но, думаю, проблема в том, что 0 не инкременируется (не утверждаю).

```
class One
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int s = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            s = s + s++;
            System.out.println(s); // тут s = 0; (уже после отработки цикла)
        }
    }
}
```

Если придать s значение 1, тогда получим

```
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
```

По-моему, это то, что требовалось. в первой строке значение 2 что означает что при выводе на System.out.println(); инкременация ещё не произошла, иначе бы было 3.

Comment: DroidAlex, s = s + s++; и s += s++; - одинаковые записи += пишется для удобства. Компиллятор всё равно выполняет одни и те же действия.

arachnoden,нет. постинкремент s сработает после выполнения операции +;
т.е. если бы был код 
int s = 0, k = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
   k = s++;
   System.out.println(s);  //1
  }
то s было бы равно 1 в строке 1 уже в первой итерации

Comment: Инкременация произойдёт не после закрытия блока `(})`, а после `System.out.println(s);` который java и считает концом блока.

Comment: Да нет же! arachnoden,если есть желание - проверьте)
в System.out.println(s); в первой итерации s будет равно 1,а не нулю
i есстественно будет равно 0 как и должно быть

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ++i // сначала i увеличивается на 1, потом присваивается к а
b = i++ // сначала i присваивается к b, потом увеличивается на 1
```

Разные компиляторы могут по разному обрабатывать эти операции, поэтому советуется не злоупотреблять такими конструкциями.
Неплохая статья есть на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/crazydev/88185/) про конструкцию `i = i++ + ++i;`

Comment: Какие ещё разные компиляторы? Вопрос про Java. А у Java есть чёткая JLS, которая говорит что точно должно произойти.

Comment: просто обратил на это внимание, да тут конкретно про яву, но в другом языке можно получить другие значения

Comment: к тому же данный код:
a = ++i // сначала i увеличивается на 1, потом присваивается к а
b = i++ // сначала i присваивается к b, потом увеличивается на 1

отработает одинаково в любом компилляторе который знает про инкремент\декремент