# Присвоить себя инкриментуя

Tags: java

```
x=10;
x=x++;
print("x = "x);
________
x = 10
```

Что делается в памяти, и как это понять?

Comment: Ну, ё-мое, народ. В любом учебнике это есть.

Answer (score 1):

[Как работает постинкремент оператор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/43736/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)