# Как работает и выполняется цикл for?

Tags: java

Друзья! Вот такой пример:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        int sum = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= 5; sum += i++) {
            System.out.println("Сумма " + sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Прошелся дебагом не пойму, почему выводится с 0, а не 1, если там sum += i++, должно быть 1? Вот что выводится

```
Сумма 0
Сумма 1
Сумма 3
Сумма 6
Сумма 10
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему x = x++ не приводит к увеличению значения x в цикле?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/608115/204271)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Рассмотрим первую итерацию:

Сначала инициализируется `i` (`i = 1`), потом произойдет проверка (`i <= 5`), потом выведется значение в `println`, потом выполнится выражение `sum = sum + i++;`. Т.е. сначала выведется `sum`, а только потом выполнится `sum = sum + i++;`.

За картинку сорри, нарисовал как смог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разберем как выполняется выражение в шапке. `sum = 0, i = 1`. После `sum = sum + i` (`sum = 0 + 1`) выполнится `++` и `i` станет равно 2. Более подробно о том, [как работает инкремент в Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java)(enSO).

Comment: Не понял почему sum += i++ это 4? Как это первый раз так пропускается?

Comment: @ПетровИван нет, это очередность действий. Сначала 1), потом 2)...4), потом опять 1) и т.д.

Comment: А почему sum += i++ не 2 ?

Comment: Впервые такую конструкцию вижу если честно

Comment: Антон, are you here?:)

Comment: @ПетровИван ибо по правилам `for` последний блок срабатывает после каждой итерации, а не все вместе.

Comment: @ПетровИван потому что так работает i++. Если вы хотите, что бы i сначала стала равно 2, а потом прибавилась, то надо использовать ++i. [объяснение, как работает i++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/43736/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)

Comment: @ПетровИван оператор i++ СНАЧАЛА возвращает значение i, и только после след. операции увеличивает его на 1. Т.е., i станет равно 2 только ПОСЛЕ операции присваивания для sum,  после шага 4 и перед шагом 1.

Comment: @AntonSorokin, я кажется понял, получается первый раз когда начинает работать цикл for, в итерации происходит вот такое: 0 = 0 +1; //Но 1 это же постфиксная форма и она так сказать работает в фоновом режиме и поэтому в sout выдается Сумма: 0 и потом по накатанной да?

Comment: @AntonSorokin мне больше всего интересно как он выдал 0 первый, если там sum += i++ это, 0 = 0 + 1; и по сути должен был вывести 1, а не Сумма: 0;

Comment: @ПетровИван да потому что sum = 0. я же вам написал все по шагам. СНАЧАЛА ВЫВОДИТСЯ PRINTLN, А ПОТОМ ВЫЧИСЛЯЕТСЯ ВЫРАЖЕНИЕ! Смотрите по картинке. 1 - то что выполняется сначала, 2 - после 1, 3 после 2, 4 после 3.И даже стрелочки там есть. Почитайте как работает цикл for.

Comment: @AntonSorokin спасибо большое, оказывается у меня был такой пробел большой жесть, спасибо Антон! Извиняюсь :)

Comment: @ПетровИван ничего страшного, все мы учимся, я у себя тоже иногда пробелы нахожу, как говориться нет предела совершенства.